# Vertical Align a Bread Crumb using ASP.Net <asp:SiteMapPath> control

Tags: .net, asp.net, css

Using a "asp:SiteMapPath" control along with Web.sitemap, I'm able to get a bread crumb navigate horizontally like this

Home > Manage People > Requirements >

Can a bread crumb navigation using a "asp:SiteMapPath" control be changed ? so that it comes vertically like this

- Home >
- Manage People >
- Requirements >

Thanks in advance,
Easwar.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<ul style="list-style-type: none;">
<asp:SiteMapPath ID="SiteMapPath1" runat="server" >
<NodeTemplate>
    <li>
        <a href='<%# Eval("url") %>' title='<%# Eval("description") %>' >
            <%# Eval("title") %>
        </a>
    </li>
</NodeTemplate>
</asp:SiteMapPath>
</ul>
```

Comment: Thanks OneHalf. But I don't need the bread crumb to come in a <ul> <li> format. I was not able to put the bread crumb in a vertical format in my question, so I used the bulleted list style in my question for the bread crumb. It should be vertical aligned without that bullet list. Please help.

Comment: Add style to the ul element with list-style-type: none;

Comment: Great. Thanks a lot. Will try this and let you know.